# How can I change my Heroku website to a custom domain provided by Bluehost?

Tags: heroku, dns, bluehost

I am new to Bluehost as well as Heroku website.
I have deployed my website to Heroku already.

This is my website:
https://vietalk-project.herokuapp.com/

I have searched around but all the guides giving different answer and I also found an answer from Stackoverflow but it has been around 8 years so I really want an updated answer that I could implement towards this process.

Here is the steps that I follow:

1. I have added the domain to heroku settings. [image: Heroku Domains]
2. I have changed the bluehost dns host record to point to the dns target provided by heroku.
   (I have also tried the dns host record to point to the actual website in this case is vietalk.org like in the picture [image: DNS record in bluehost]and I also try heroku.app.com in this case is vietalk-project.herokuapp.com) But none of this works.

I found some answers that says using Heroku Command Line but I wonder where should I use it: in my terminal or the terminal in Heroku app if that exists.

So can anyone provide the actual step into customize the domain with Heroku please?
I have contacted the Bluehost and they said using vietalk.org in dns host record and wait for the dns propagation but I waited and saw nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CNAME` isn't correct.

`www` should point to the DNS target Heroku gives you, not to the domain you want to use. Based on your screenshot, it looks like it should point to something starting with `infinite-rook-b352...`.

Copy that entire string and paste it into the Bluehost DNS panel. Then save your DNS settings and wait for them to propagate. If you prefer, you can also get the DNS target string [by running `heroku domains` on the command-line](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains).

The `ftp`, `cpanel`, and `webmail` `CNAME` records shouldn't be pointing at Heroku as it doesn't provde any of those features. You probably don't need them at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have changed the dns record to the one that is targeted by Heroku. I will wait for a few days for the dns to propagate and hope for the best.